# Lucene and Django with Limited Memory

Tags: python, django, lucene, solr

I'm running a Django application on a shared web server with limited application memory. I want to incorporate Lucene for a search functionality. What are my options, given the limited amount memory?

I thought about using Solr via [solrpy](http://code.google.com/p/solrpy/), but it looks like Solr is very memory hungry. Do you think it would be possible to reduce its memory footprint to a mere 15-20MB for a small dataset (only thousands of sentences).

I would prefer solutions that require only Python, but I am also open to other suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not going to get the JVM to even fit in 15MB. I wouldn't try to run Solr unless there's at least 200MB memory.

You could try [Woosh](http://whoosh.ca/), a pure Python search library, or [Xapian](http://xapian.org/), which is in C++. [Haystack](http://haystacksearch.org/) makes it easy to integrate either into Django.

Comment: I've used Xapian + Django in a limited memory environment successfully.